# Why is the Flutter timeago package not displaying correctly, or is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart, timeago, flutter-packages

This is where I get the DateTime values to see the sample output.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print('Datetime UTC: ${DateTime.now().toUtc()}');
    print('Date from Json: $date');
    print('Time ago from Json: ${timeago.format(date)}');
    print('Time ago from Json using UTC: ${timeago.format(date, clock: DateTime.now().toUtc())}');


    return GestureDetector(...
```

and this becomes the output display. My current time is 2020-03-07 09:42 am.
Time "Time ago from Json:" is correct, but "Time ago from Json using UTC:" is not.

```
I/flutter (27117): Datetime UTC: 2020-03-07 01:42:59.742488Z
I/flutter (27117): Date from Json: 2020-03-07 00:32:31.000
I/flutter (27117): Time ago from Json: 9 hours ago
I/flutter (27117): Time ago from Json using UTC: 9 hours ago
```

same output, using timeago package

Comment: i see that maybe the reason, system time is the reason if its output becomes the same

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentTime = DateTime.now();
var jsonTime = $date


print(timeago.format(currentTime.subtract(jsonTime));
```

If you look at the arguments of `timeago.format()` you can see that it takes a `Duration` as an argument.

Comment: Aparently this is not true (anymore?): The docs say: package:timeago/src/timeago.dart String format(   DateTime date, {   String locale,   DateTime clock,   bool allowFromNow = false, })